# Student, automating email to an admin on creation of a new user powershell

Tags: powershell, email, automation

trying to send an email upon the creation of a new user to the admin.
This appears to work the first time but then fails to run a second time.
I think its an issue with me creating a new object the second time, but am unfamiliar with PScredential, and how to call it a second time instead of creating it again, I'm assuming it would be some form of if statement, but I don't know what to call in the if.

here is my Code

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “Password” -AsPlainText -Force

$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('38da1ca9daf082',"$password")

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer 'smtp.mailtrap.io' -Credential $cred -UseSsl -From 'server@gmail.com' -To 'admin@gmail.com' -Subject 'TEST'
```

and this is the error message

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
At line:3 char:9
+ $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('38da1ca ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: Could this be the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970505/new-object-cannot-find-an-overload-for-pscredential-and-the-argument-count

Comment: Do you still need help with this issue? If so I will write a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets see the documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=pscore-6.2.0

We can see there are 2 constructors

```
PSCredential(PSObject)
```

or

```
PSCredential(String, SecureString)
```

It looks like in the post example `PSCredential(String, SecureString)` was trying to be used.

In the example

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “Password” -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('38da1ca9daf082',"$password")
```

Because `"$Password"` was put in quotes it has turned the `SecureString` into a regular `String`.

The Fix is to remove the qoutes `"`

Here is a working copy

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “Password” -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('38da1ca9daf082',$password)
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer 'smtp.mailtrap.io' -Credential $cred -UseSsl -From 'server@gmail.com' -To 'admin@gmail.com' -Subject 'TEST'
```